# how to use the tcsetgprp function

Tags: c

this is a simple example to use the tcsetpgrp function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void judge(void){
    pid_t pid;
    pid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
    if(pid == -1){
            perror("tcgetpgrp");
            return;
    }else if(pid == getpgrp()){
            printf("foreground\n");
    }else{
            printf("background\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_IGN);
    judge();
    int result;
    result = tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO,getpgrp());
    if(result == -1){
            perror("tcsetpgrp");
            return -1;
    }
    judge();
    return 0;
}
```

i will run it in the background,as my expection,the output like:

todd911@virtual-machine:./a.out &

[1] 15894

todd911@virtual-machine:~$ background

foreground

but in fact,it act like:

todd911@virtual-machine:./a.out &

[1] 15894

todd911@virtual-machine:~$ background

foreground

exit

at last,the terminal exit automatically,is anybody know the reason?

Comment: Its return 0 at the end of your main

Comment: the problem is my terminal exit automatically,like i execute the exit command in the shell.

Comment: You are probably confusing your shell, by manipulating fg/bg process groups behind its back.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that if the process group that controls the terminal exits, then the shell or terminal will decide the session has ended and kill it off.  I tried your program on gnome-terminal with ksh93 and bash and it did not exit.